# Setting /var/www/html to chmod 777 on a development site

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

Is it OK to set /var/www/html to chmod 777 -R on a development site?

I usually do that on my laptop. I do it right with a server.

Are there any problems with doing it this way?

Comment: Make that `775` instead!

Answer (score 0):

No, bad habits should always be avoided. And if you set your development environment incorrectly you are likely to copy something over to the production server. Unintended I am sure but I have seen it happen before.

Depending on how many users are developing: either 700 if it is one user or 750 if it is more than 1 user (and I count you, the webserver user and any other software you use that needs a user as separate users) could be more than enough.

Comment: Is it not secure to create a new group, adding users and www-data to that group, and setting permissions to 775?

Comment: Why does others need any permission at all in your setup? Why does group need execute permissions in your setup? (That should only be needed for the apache user as that user is also the owner) And ... it is not about "not secure" but about "more or less secure".

Comment: The apache user for me is www-data. That's why I set the group permissions to 775. What would you recommend as an ideal configuration?

Comment: I use root:root for the complete website. Then I change directories who needs to be writeable to www-data. I use ACL in the most restriced way. Perms are 664 (775 for dirs).

Comment: @JudoOpsec you got a user and a group so why does others need read/write permissions? Does the group need execute permissions? If yes: 770 for dirs. otherwise I would use 750 for dirs. And files are 1 lower (so 660 or 640).